# PayPal PayFlow Pro - Recurring Billing - Credit Card Verification - CVV

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, payflowpro

With regards to the PayPal PayFlow Pro service, is it possible to pass through a CVV number when creating a recurring profile?

Currently on our site we only ask for a credit card number and expiry date when creating a recurring profile however we would now like to request the CVV number to improve card holder verification and I guess ultimately reduce the likelihood of potential fraud.

According to the documentation:

https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_payflowpro_recurringbilling_guide.pdf

CVV isn't listed as a parameter for the "ADD" action as part of the recurring billing service however if you do pass it as a parameter, the response back contains information related to CVV validation as follows:

```
CVV2MATCH => N,
PROCCVV2 => N
```

What's interesting is that testing this in the PayPal Sandbox with an invalid CVV number, the response I get back is as follows:

```
Request:
TRXTYPE => R,
TENDER => C,
ACTION => A,
ACCT => 4111-XXXX-XXXX-1111,
CVV2 => XXX,
EXPDATE => 0518,
START => 04162014,
MAXFAILPAYMENTS => 1,
RETRYNUMDAYS => 2,
TERM => 0,
PAYPERIOD => YEAR,
AMT => 50.00,
PROFILENAME[9] => test_1234,
OPTIONALTRX => A,
COMMENT1[14] => Recurring Plan,

Response:
RESULT => 0,
RPREF => R1056C75AF08,
PROFILEID => RT0000014434,
RESPMSG => Approved,
TRXRESULT => 0,
TRXPNREF => A70A6ABE7817,
TRXRESPMSG => Verified,
AUTHCODE => 407PNI,
CVV2MATCH => N,
HOSTCODE => A,
PROCCVV2 => N,
VISACARDLEVEL => 12
```

As you can see although the CVV validation failed "CVV2MATCH => N" (which means there was no match), the transaction went through successfully "RESULT => 0, TRXRESULT => 0" and the recurring profile was subsequently created.

One would expect that a non-matching CVV would result in the transaction failing not succeeding.

Is there something that I've incorrectly assumed or are doing wrong? Is there a setting somewhere in PayPal Manager that needs to be enabled/disabled to deny transactions if CVV validation fails or is this simply some bug in the PayPal Sandbox.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Security code services are supported on the Payflow platform, though not required in all cases. You should be able to create a "Fraud Filter" within your manager account that will act on the CVV2 response as you see fit.  To access these filters login to manager.paypal.com and click on "Service Settings."  From there click the sub-heading "Fraud Protection."  Here you will be able to construct custom filters based on the results returned for each transaction.

Hope this helps!